# Will this charger damage my phone?

Tags: usb, charging, nexus-5x

I have a [3 port USB-C charger from Aukey](https://www.aukey.com/products/3-port-car-charger-with-quick-charge-3-0-2/) that for the past weeks worked well with my Nexus 5X when used with an old ATX power supply as power source.

I found critical reviews on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018TGGH4E) (link to US website, but same type of issues on DE and IT as well) where the product stops working or even fries the phones after some time.

I am using exclusively the USB-C port, the other ones cannot charge the Nexux 5X as fast. I am using the original Nexus 5X USB-C cable, not the one provided by AUKEY (it is said to be low quality).

I decided to take it apart and I measured the voltage on the power pins of USB-C while charging and while the charger is powered by 12.2 V from a DC-DC power supply. The source is therefore cleaner than a car electric circuit would be.

I measured with this conditions on the output port 5.10-5.38 V. The tester gives me 5.01 on a LM7805 used as calibration.

Nexus 5X is not Quick charge 3 compatible, therefore it does not negotiate voltages continuously variable above 5 V, in theory it should only jump to 9 V but I haven't seen it, even if the charger could provide it.

Will the 5.4 V damage my Nexus 5X, as it happened to (other) smartphones from the reviews? After all, USB tolerates up to 5.25 V only.

Comment: [How to select a Non OEM USB Type C charger or cable for my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/175876/how-to-select-a-non-oem-usb-type-c-charger-or-cable-for-my-device) may help - please go through the blogs of sources mentioned especially as your device is said to have a non standard charger. My 2C, it won't hurt since  cable resistance, and port resistance will come in play to create a drop. Even before fast charging, there were 5.3 V chargers that didn't hurt