# How to select a Non OEM USB Type C charger or cable for my device?

Tags: usb, charging, google-pixel

Internet is replete with reports of problems of USB Type C accessories. Also reported here, [Can a faulty Micro-USB cable cause damage to your device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/172985/131553)

How do I go about selecting right cable or charger, assuming I have a Pixel?

**Note:** This is a self answered question drawing from the spadework in answering a different question and felt it may be useful to share, given Type C is gaining popularity.  Additional answers are of of course welcome! Guidelines in answer are not restricted to Pixel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**USB C Chargers/ Cables are a minefield** - *In implementation*

- The standards (as they should) are said to clear and consistent but implementation has been shoddy causing multiple problems and even burnouts. One Plus pioneered Type C on Android (One Plus Two) and set a [wrong precedent](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/11/oneplus-admits-that-its-selling-dodgy-usb-type-c-cables-and-adapters/) by saving few cents, maybe, with a non- standard resistor . They are not the only ones, Apple and *Google* too , to an extent ( not to forget [laptops](https://www.theverge.com/2016/2/4/10916264/usb-c-russian-roulette-power-cords) )
- Coming to Google, sample this, quoted from reddit post [Please ELI5:Chargers, charging cables, and safety for my Pixel](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/5bjx65/please_eli5_chargers_charging_cables_and_safety/)
  where Nathan K  , says :

  - On buying USB cables having USB_IF certification (USB C )

> USB-IF Certification testing costs money -- lots of money. $10,000 per product. So a lot of generic manufacturers simply do not do it. Instead, they make products by the seat-of-their-pants. Others, like Apple and **Google** say "Screw the USB-IF, we know better than them. We can **self-certify**." So products you buy in an Apple Store or from Google may not have a USB-IF logo, but are (mostly) good. (*There are some exceptions I've discovered, noted in my list.*)

(Emphasis supplied)

- On Chargers

> ...Google sells people on buying a $35 USB-PD charger its own product doesn't even utilize. The only time it would be used is with expensive peripherals like charge-through hubs.

( I am not sure what exactly is *not utilized*, haven't researched further   )

**So, whom to trust ?**

Nathan K is an independent tester, not affiliated to anyone ([Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/collection/UQ94NB) ). Benson Leung is a Google software engineer ( [Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/+BensonLeung) ). Individually and collectively, they carry out tests of *practically* any USB Type C equipment , chargers and cables and publish them on Google Plus.

They are doing a yeoman service by advising users on choosing right USB Type C accessories and their testing has at times forced prominent brands to remove products from sale ([Anker, for example, see their blogs for more examples](https://plus.google.com/+BensonLeung/posts/CEnvJhhTCip)

Browse their blogs for the right accessory for your device and you may reach out to them on reddit / Google Plus

**For Pixel users**

You have it on a platter ! Nathan and Benson together they have curated a list of accessories that are tested for your device ([details here](https://plus.google.com/102612254593917101378/posts/1PJZT2g61Ag) ). Consider buying charger and cable based on the recommendations linked above (make sure look at the column titled "IR Drop compensation" (should have that). That is a very important feature to correctly charge

**You will notice that some negatively or low  rated accessories include OEMs like LG, google and Huawei !**

**Disclaimer:** Haven't owned any device with Type C charging and nor I am affiliated anyway with Nathan or Benson

**Additional Information**

- USB Type C over Power Delivery (PD) , is different from Qualcomm Quick Charging. [Qualcomm's Quick Charge will not work on a Pixel. The charger will default to a spec-standard current and voltage](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/forum/AAAAb4-OgUscTCRr2tUon4/?hl=by)
- [What are USB PD Power Rules?](https://plus.google.com/+BensonLeung/posts/71FgNerD8TB)
- [Can Qualcomm QC and USB Type-C coexist on the same connector?](https://plus.google.com/+BensonLeung/posts/cEvVQLXhyRX)- No. Type C specs forbid that (though you will find cables that claim to do this on market- avoid them like plague). For the same reason,  Nexus 6P and 5X do not support QC
- USB-PD can only work with a C-C USB cables. A to C cables - ([pic here](http://www.androidauthority.com/best-usb-type-c-cables-682801/) ) cannot charge as per specs (max current possible is 1.5 A)

Comment: The Google Plus links are broken.

Comment: @Flimm That's unfortunately true, after Google groups were pulled down. I tried reaching to Nathan for alternate links but didn't get a reply. I didn't prune the dead links hoping that some reader would be able to provide