# using galaxy s8 usb-c cable into lg g5?

Tags: charging

I have questioned my LG G5 I had for 2 months today first time using different cable because I forgot my cable in a friend's car so I had to charged my phone and I used my brother galaxy S8 USB-c cable (original s8 cable) and my original LG wall charger is will cause any damage can damage my phone?

Comment: *Questioned*? I suppose you mean *Charged*. Please [edit]

Comment: USB type C cables are a mess because of different standards by OEMs. [LG G5](https://www.androidauthority.com/htc-10-lg-g5-breach-usb-type-c-spec-688558/) is no exception and adds to this . See [more](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/175876/131553) for such misery. While I can't say it is fine or not, my suggestion would be to avoid charging from mains but use a laptop to charge -slower but safer