# Do all USB C data/charge cables support Quick Charge?

Tags: usb, charging, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi Mi 8 which uses a USB C connector for charging. As long as my phone supports Fast Charging, do I need any sort of special USB C cable to take advantage of the fastest charging speed that my device supports?

I read in Wikipedia that "All USB-C cables must be able to carry a minimum of 3 A current" however I see some USB C cables advertised as supporting up to only 2A.

NOTE: my charger supports 3A 5V, 2A 18V, and 1.5A 12V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer **It depends, may or may not**

- Any USB C cable will not serve the purpose . You need to search your device forums and some sources mentioned in answer here (which also includes references to technical details if you are keen) [How to select a Non OEM USB Type C charger or cable for my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/175876/131553)
- This is a good read for USB C state of affairs, for charging and data speeds too [It’s 2018 and USB Type-C is still a mess](https://www.androidauthority.com/state-of-usb-type-c-870996/). See the wide variation in power even with standard OEM cables weekend used with different phones

[image]